# How to change font size using document.execCommand?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to change the `font-size` of selected text inside a `div` using the `document.execCommand` by using this function:

```
var execFontSize = function (size, unit) {
  var spanString = $('<span/>', {
    'text': document.getSelection()
  }).css('font-size', size + unit).prop('outerHTML');
  document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, spanString);
};
```

However, this function only works on the selected text. If I try to then write in the `div` the text will not have changed size. I do not want to use `document.execCommand("fontSize", false, 5)` as you are limited to only 7 sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.execCommand` by default generates HTML markup, so - as you mentioned, you're limited with `h1` to `h2`. However you can set `styleWithCSS` to `true` so `style` attribute will be appended and CSS used instead of HTML markups.

Ref.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand